# video Enters Fullscreen "Live Broadcast" Mode on iOS Despite playsinline Attribute in Standalone PWA

Tags: ios, html5-video, progressive-web-apps

I've encountered a consistent issue on iOS devices when setting the playsinline attribute for video playback. Despite this setting, the video transitions into a "Live broadcast" mode, automatically entering fullscreen mode. This behavior mirrors a previously reported issue in (https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview/issues/1452.)

The fullscreen "Live broadcast" mode allows for a swipe action to revert the video to inline play, but this workaround is less than ideal for user experience. More critically, when running in standalone Progressive Web App (PWA) mode, this behavior completely locks up the application, preventing any further interaction.

I'm currently exploring alternative solutions, such as repainting the video onto a canvas element, to circumvent this fullscreen takeover. However, I'm unsure if this approach will resolve the underlying issue or if there are more direct solutions available.

Has anyone else faced this problem or have suggestions on how to maintain inline video playback without triggering the fullscreen mode, especially in the standalone PWA context?

Any guidance or workarounds would be greatly appreciated.

Video attached on the github issue :

https://github.com/collab-project/videojs-record/issues/714